# ^C causing PROMPT='$(my_prompt_function)' to never be called

Tags: zsh

I am trying to execute a more complex function that constructs the PROMPT string in ZSH, and under normal circumstances, it is working.  However, because I have the following TRAPINT to print "^C" when I send SIGINT at the prompt, it does not work (it does not call my function).

### .zshrc

```
TRAPINT() {
    print -n "^C"
    return $(( 128 + $1 ))
}
my_prompt_function() {
    echo '>'
}
setopt PROMPT_SUBST
PROMPT='$(my_prompt_function)'
```

However, if I press <kbd>^C</kbd> at the prompt, it just hangs:

```
>
>^C
# ...hangs here until I press <Enter>
```

How do I tell, from within TRAPINT, that I am at the prompt, vs. in a running program, so that I can not return an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the command substitution is not evaluated after the shell was interrupted in that way.

You could work around it by using the `precmd` hook:

```sh
precmd () {
    MYPROMPT='>'
}
setopt PROMPT_SUBST
PROMPT='${MYPROMPT}'
```

`precmd` is run before each prompt. Note that `precmd` is not re-executed in cases where the prompt is just redrawn without running a command-line (like in this case). It still works as the value of `MYPROMPT` remains even without running `precmd`.

---

- You also can have multiple `precmd` functions. You can manage them with the `add-zsh-hook` module:

  ```sh
  autoload -Uz add-zsh-hook
  myprompt_function () {
      MYPROMPT='>'
  }
  add-zsh-hook precmd myprompt_function
  setopt PROMPT_SUBST
  PROMPT='${MYPROMPT}'
  ```
- You can also use the special array variable `psvar`, the membersr of which can be accessed with the prompt escape `%v` or `%Nv` where `N` is the array index to be displayed:

  ```sh
  precmd () {
      psvar[3]='>'
  }
  PROMPT='%3v'
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I am accepting Adaephon's answer, but posting here to show my final solution:

```
TRAPINT() {
  if [ "$IS_PROMPTING" == true ]; then
    print -n "^C"
    return $(( 128 + $1 ))
  fi
}
precmd() {
  IS_PROMPTING=true
  PROMPT=$(command-that-generates-prompt-string)
}
preexec() {
  IS_PROMPTING=false
}
```

TRAPINT conditionally checks to see if the user is at the prompt or within an executing command via a flag that is appropriately set via precmd/preexec.